# How to get the project name in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gmf

How do I get the name of the current eclipse project? I'm in a GMF view and need the projectname when some submenu of the popup menu ist used.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This [GMF class](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.gmf/tests/org.eclipse.gmf.tests/src/org/eclipse/gmf/tests/rt/EditHelpersTest.java?root=Modeling_Project&view=co) has a straightforward answer, if you have access to the ResourcesPlugin name:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(myBundleName);
```

The generic answer (from a [potentially outdated code](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg03446.html)) could be like (if you have an editor opened):

```
IEditorPart  editorPart =
getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();

if(editorPart  != null)
{
    IFileEditorInput input = (IFileEditorInput)editorPart.getEditorInput() ;
    IFile file = input.getFile();
    IProject activeProject = file.getProject();
    String activeProjectName = activeProject.getName();
    //... use activeProjectName 
}
```

If no editor is opened:

```
   IViewPart [] parts =
      MyPlugin.getDefault().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViews();
    IProject activeProject = null;

    for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
    {
        if(parts[i] instanceof ResourceNavigator)
        {
            ResourceNavigator navigator = (ResourceNavigator)parts[i];
            StructuredSelection sel   =
              (StructuredSelection)navigator.getTreeViewer().getSelection();
            IResource resource = (IResource)sel.getFirstElement();
            activeProject = resource.getProject();
            break;
        }
    }
    String activeProjectName = activeProject .getName();
```

Comment: For GMF change the MyPlugin part to:

`IViewPart[] parts = {yourPluginName}DiagramEditorPlugin.getInstance().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViews();`

Your GMF plugin name can be found in your .genmodel.

Answer (score 8):

Using the selection service will give you the currently selected object, you can then check the selection type and get the project based on the selection.

If you create an ISelectionListener and register as a listener on the ISelectionService, you'll be notified whenever the active selection changes, and be given a reference to the selection and the owning part.

```
ISelectionListener listener = new ISelectionListener() {
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcePart, ISelection selection) {
        setSourcePart(sourcePart);
        setSelection(selection);
    }
};

...
//register the listener
selectionService.addSelectionListener(listener);

...
//either get the selection service and get the selection, or use the stored version from the listener
ISelectionService selectionService = 
    Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();

ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection();

if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
    Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();

    IProject project;
    if (element instanceof IResource) {
        project= ((IResource)element).getProject();
    } else if (element instanceof PackageFragmentRootContainer) {
        IJavaProject jProject = 
            ((PackageFragmentRootContainer)element).getJavaProject();
        project = jProject.getProject();
    } else if (element instanceof IJavaElement) {
        IJavaProject jProject= ((IJavaElement)element).getJavaProject();
        project = jProject.getProject();
    }
} else if (selection instanceof ITextSelection) {
    if(sourcePart instanceof JavaEditor) {
        IJavaElement element = SelectionConverter.resolveEnclosingElement(sourcePart, selection);
        project = element.getJavaProject().getProject();
    }
}
```

See this [article on the Eclipse selection service](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html) for more details.

Comment: Probably a more accurate answer than mine. +1

Comment: +1 but better use PlatformUI.getWorkbench() instead of Workbench.getInstance().

Answer (score 5):

I have created a nice function from the posts above, plus added some updates. Works with current eclipse.

```
public static IProject getCurrentSelectedProject() {
    IProject project = null;
    ISelectionService selectionService = 
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();

    ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection();

    if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();

        if (element instanceof IResource) {
            project= ((IResource)element).getProject();
        } else if (element instanceof PackageFragmentRoot) {
            IJavaProject jProject = 
                ((PackageFragmentRoot)element).getJavaProject();
            project = jProject.getProject();
        } else if (element instanceof IJavaElement) {
            IJavaProject jProject= ((IJavaElement)element).getJavaProject();
            project = jProject.getProject();
        }
    }
    return project;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rich Seller and VonC have both provided good answers but they didn't seem complete enough/used internal classes. I have come up with the following.

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
{
  ....

  // Register to be notified about selections
  getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService()
      .addPostSelectionListener(this);

  // Detect the current selection
  detectCurrentSelection();
}

@Override
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection)
{
  IProject project = convertSelection(part, selection);
  setProject(project);
}

private void detectCurrentSelection()
{
  IProject project = null;

  IWorkbenchWindow window = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow();
  IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage();

  if (activePage != null)
  {
    IEditorPart part = activePage.getActiveEditor();

    if (part != null)
    {
      project = convertSelection(part);
    }
    else
    {
      IViewReference[] viewReferences = activePage.getViewReferences();

      for (IViewReference viewRef : viewReferences)
      {
        IViewPart view = viewRef.getView(false);
        ISelection selection = null;

        if (view instanceof IPackagesViewPart)
        {
          IPackagesViewPart viewPart = (IPackagesViewPart) view;
          TreeViewer treeViewer = viewPart.getTreeViewer();
          selection = treeViewer.getSelection();
        }
        else if (view instanceof CommonNavigator)
        {
          CommonNavigator navigator = (CommonNavigator) view;
          CommonViewer commonViewer = navigator.getCommonViewer();
          selection = commonViewer.getSelection();
        }

        if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)
        {
          IStructuredSelection structuredSelection = (IStructuredSelection) selection;

          project = convertSelection(structuredSelection);

          if (project != null)
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  setProject(project);
}

private IProject convertSelection(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection)
{
  IProject project = null;
  if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)
  {
    IStructuredSelection structuredSelection = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
    project = convertSelection(structuredSelection);
  }
  else if (selection instanceof ITextSelection)
  {
    if (part instanceof IEditorPart)
    {
      IEditorPart editorPart = (IEditorPart) part;
      IResource resource = (IResource)editorPart.getEditorInput().getAdapter(IResource.class);
      if (resource != null)
      {
        project = resource.getProject();
      }
    }
  }

  return project;
}

private IProject convertSelection(IEditorPart part)
{
  IProject project = null;
  IResource resource = (IResource)part.getEditorInput().getAdapter(IResource.class);
  if (resource != null)
  {
    project = resource.getProject();
  }
  return project;
}

private IProject convertSelection(IStructuredSelection structuredSelection)
{
  IProject project = null;
  Object element = structuredSelection.getFirstElement();

  if (element instanceof IResource)
  {
    project = ((IResource) element).getProject();
  }
  else if (element instanceof IJavaElement)
  {
    IJavaElement javaElement = (IJavaElement) element;
    project = javaElement.getJavaProject().getProject();
  }
  else if (element instanceof IAdaptable)
  {
    IAdaptable adaptable = (IAdaptable) element;
    IWorkbenchAdapter adapter = (IWorkbenchAdapter) adaptable.getAdapter(IWorkbenchAdapter.class);
    if (adapter != null)
    {
      Object parent = adapter.getParent(adaptable);
      if (parent instanceof IJavaProject)
      {
        IJavaProject javaProject = (IJavaProject) parent;
        project = javaProject.getProject();
      }
    }
  }

  return project;
}
```