# How do I get a reference to the current project in an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating an editor for Eclipse. Right now the editor fires up with the user creates a new file with the appropriate extension. My question is, how can I get a reference to the project in which the file resides? For example, say I have a workspace with 2 projects, P1 and P2. I right click P2 and create a new file, can I get a reference to P2 from this somehow?

Ultimately I need to reference the AST or Java Model of the project but even a String identifying the project would work.

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206095/how-to-get-the-project-name-in-eclipse help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, the answer is simply IFile.getProject() would work...

If you work with a FileEditorInput in the init() method, you could use the following code to obtain the searched project resource:

FileEditorInput fileInput = (FileEditorInput) input;
fileInput.getFile().getProject();