# Eclipse workbench application start up problem

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have created one workbench application plugin not eclipse rcp application. I have not created any plugin template for that workbench application.
Now When I run the workbench application Activator is not calling. I put **System.out.println("Insided start()")** inside the start method of the
**Activator.java**. But it is not calling the start method. How I make call the start method? But when I make the option,**Autostart=true** in the runconfiguration,plug-ins,
It is starting the activator. But the problem is When I call **IWorkbenchWindow window = Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();**
It is giving the error message saying could not create the workbench window. This error message is giving only when I make this plugin as AutoStart=true. What couldbe the problem?

---

Following are the error message I get..When I use

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
>     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:92)   at
>   myworkbenchplugin.Activator.custom(Activator.java:43)     at
>   myworkbenchplugin.Activator.start(Activator.java:36)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

Answer (score 1):

As you already saw, you need to manage your **[OSGi bundle manifest](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/bundle_manifest.html)** to specify the right activation policy. Note though that:

> The `Eclipse-AutoStart` and `Eclipse-LazyStart` headers have been deprecated in Eclipse 3.4.
>   As of the OSGi R4.1 specification the lazy activation policy has been adopted by the OSGi specification. The new OSGi bundle manifest header **`Bundle-ActivationPolicy`** can be used to specify a lazy activation policy.
>
> The Equinox Framework version 3.4 or later will continue to support the deprecated `Eclipse-LazyStart` and `Eclipse-AutoStart` headers.
>   Bundle developers that want their bundles to work across other OSGi Framework implementations should add the **`Bundle-ActivationPolicy`** header to their manifest. In most cases you can simply add the following header:

```
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

See [OSGi LazyStart design](http://www.osgi.org/Design/LazyStart).
In your case, you can try `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy;exclude:="yourPluginId"` if you want to be sure your plugin starts no matter what.

For getting the Active `WorkbenchWindow`, you can use `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()` as detailed in [How to get the project name in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206095/how-to-get-the-project-name-in-eclipse).

Comment: thanks for the information.

still I am getting the same problem. When I used PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(), it is showing the exception that Workbench has not created. But when I Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(), it is showing 
window is IWorkbenchWindow is null.

One more thing all these exceptions I got when I debug. It was not coming in the console. Any idea why it was not showing in
the console? Some exceptions it is showing in the console.

Comment: no I dont have the exact error message. When I debug only came to know that it is throwing exception.. and that exception is Workebnch not created. But when I use the code Workench.getInstance().getActiveWorkebenchWindow(), it returning null.

Answer (score 1):

If you start your plugin when Eclipse starts, the Activator.start() will be called before the workbench is fully started. You need to push the code inside a UIJob/WorkbenchJob in the Activator, so that it will be called after the workbench windows are ready.