# How to obtain project name in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I want to get project information without `IProject` class, because in Indigo, not work (not exist). Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206095/how-to-get-the-project-name-in-eclipse

Comment: What do you mean with "not exist"? IProject exists and works in every eclipse version. Probably you should refine your question.

Answer (score 1):

Project Name:

```
String fullprojpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
int index = fullprojpath.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
System.out.println(fullprojpath.substring(index+1));
```

Comment: `File.separator` should be used instead of `File.pathSeparator`.

Comment: @uyuyuy99 Yes it should be `File.separator`.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir").split("(.*\\" + File.separator + ")")[1]);
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I pretty much did the exact same thing as Rahul, but with no errors.